# How to use echo along with shorthand IF, ELSEIF and ELSE

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-operator

Hi,

I saw somebody else asked this before but the answers there are not what I am looking for. I would like to know what is the shorthand for expressions like this example:

```
if ($gender == 'male'){
    echo 'M;
} else if($gender == 'female'){
    echo 'F';
} else {
    echo 'undefined';
}
```

I only know what to do when there is only 2 possibilities:

```
echo ($gender == 'male' ? 'M' : 'F');
```

but what about when you have else if like in my example above?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the variable again if the statement is false and you need to add parenthesis around the entire else block

```
echo ($gender == 'male') ? 'M' : (($gender == 'female') ? 'F' : 'undefined');
```

Comment: Thank you. Thats the answer I needed.